# How to bind a raw socket to a specific interface using python in linux centOS?

Tags: python, linux, centos, raw-sockets

How to bind a raw socket to a specific interface using python in linux centOS? I have multiple interfaces like eth0, eth0:1, eth0:2,etc

Comment: I used following cURL command to send request from eth0:1   " curl--interface 10.91.56.2 http:/10.91.55.3/file0.txt"     and I was successful in generating traffic from virtual eth0:1. Can anyone guide me how to do this using python? 10.91.56.2 is my virtual eth0:1 IP interface and 10.91.55.3 is my server address...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it by using the IP address that corresponds to the desired interface.

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
s.bind(('192.168.1.100', 12345))

s = socket.socket()
s.bind(('localhost', 12345))

s = socket.socket()
s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 12345))
```

The first two above would bind to the interface with that IP address. The last one will bind to any interface. You can obtain the IP address for an interface using this [recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/439094-get-the-ip-address-associated-with-a-network-inter/).