# Bind a raw socket to an interface using python in Windows

Tags: python, windows, sockets

Reading raw packets from a socket bound to a specified interface under Windows, shows also the packets that are received on other interfaces. Is this a limitation under Windows?

```
import socket as s
HOST = '192.168.1.101' # s.gethostbyname(s.gethostname())
socket = s.socket(s.AF_INET, s.SOCK_RAW)
socket.bind((HOST, 0))

while True:
    print(str(socket.recv(1000)))
```

The code follows the example given in [How to bind a raw socket to a specific interface using python in linux centOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27032429/how-to-bind-a-raw-socket-to-a-specific-interface-using-python-in-linux-centos) and [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/socket.html). If it is possible, how can the expected result be achieved?

Comment: It might be instructive to see `route print` and `ipconfig`.

Comment: `tracert 192.168.1.100` revealed that sometimes the connections are routed through the standard gateway on the second interface. An other indicator for this is the high metric show by `route print`of 266 for the expected route compared to the standard gateway route of 20. The problem is therefore not related to Python, but to Windows switching routes. I am still looking for a way to fix the route. Or is there a way to pass not the IP but the interface the socket should bind to?

Answer (score 0):

I added to your code:

```
socket.ioctl(s.SIO_RCVALL, s.RCVALL_ON)
```

Then on Windows 7 using Python 3.5 I ran:

```
import socket as s

HOSTS = ('169.254.222.66', '10.50.220.132')
for HOST in HOSTS:
    print('---', HOST)
    socket = s.socket(s.AF_INET, s.SOCK_RAW)
    socket.bind((HOST, 0))
    socket.ioctl(s.SIO_RCVALL, s.RCVALL_ON)
    for i in range(10):
        x = socket.recvfrom(65535)
        print(x[1], ' '.join(['%02x' % b for b in x[0]][:20]))
    socket.ioctl(s.SIO_RCVALL, s.RCVALL_OFF)
```

As output I got:

```
--- 169.254.222.66
('169.254.222.66', 0) 45 00 00 8d 6e d4 40 00 80 06 00 00 a9 fe de 42 a9 fe cc 5f
('169.254.222.66', 0) 45 00 07 2d 6e d5 40 00 80 06 00 00 a9 fe de 42 a9 fe cc 5f
('169.254.222.66', 0) 45 00 09 ad 6e d7 40 00 80 06 00 00 a9 fe de 42 a9 fe cc 5f
('169.254.222.66', 0) 45 00 0a 3d 6e d9 40 00 80 06 00 00 a9 fe de 42 a9 fe cc 5f
('169.254.222.66', 0) 45 00 04 3d 6e db 40 00 80 06 00 00 a9 fe de 42 a9 fe cc 5f
('169.254.222.66', 0) 45 00 00 dd 6e dc 40 00 80 06 00 00 a9 fe de 42 a9 fe cc 5f
('169.254.222.66', 0) 45 00 07 bd 6e dd 40 00 80 06 00 00 a9 fe de 42 a9 fe cc 5f
('169.254.222.66', 0) 45 00 08 5d 6e df 40 00 80 06 00 00 a9 fe de 42 a9 fe cc 5f
('169.254.222.66', 0) 45 00 06 4d 6e e1 40 00 80 06 00 00 a9 fe de 42 a9 fe cc 5f
('169.254.222.66', 0) 45 00 06 cd 6e e3 40 00 80 06 00 00 a9 fe de 42 a9 fe cc 5f
--- 10.50.220.132
('10.50.220.158', 0) 45 00 00 a1 64 18 00 00 01 11 7e 69 0a 32 dc 9e ef ff ff fa
('10.50.220.132', 0) 45 00 00 28 7d 4e 40 00 80 06 e3 cc 0a 32 dc 84 ac d9 06 25
('10.50.220.247', 0) 45 00 00 4e 02 9e 00 00 80 11 66 a6 0a 32 dc f7 0a 32 df ff
('10.50.221.3', 0) 45 00 00 4e 35 57 00 00 80 11 33 e1 0a 32 dd 03 0a 32 df ff
('10.50.220.149', 0) 45 00 00 f1 37 5f 40 00 04 11 67 db 0a 32 dc 95 ef ff ff fa
('10.50.220.149', 0) 45 00 00 f1 b3 04 40 00 40 11 a0 30 0a 32 dc 95 ff ff ff ff
('10.50.220.247', 0) 45 00 00 4e 02 9f 00 00 80 11 66 a5 0a 32 dc f7 0a 32 df ff
('10.50.221.3', 0) 45 00 00 4e 35 58 00 00 80 11 33 e0 0a 32 dd 03 0a 32 df ff
('10.50.220.176', 0) 45 00 00 4e 19 14 00 00 80 11 50 77 0a 32 dc b0 0a 32 df ff
('10.50.221.3', 0) 45 00 00 4e 35 59 00 00 80 11 33 df 0a 32 dd 03 0a 32 df ff
```

So in my test, there was no mixing of interfaces

Comment: I tried running your code but got a different result. When binding to `169.254.222.66(255.255.255.0)` it shows packets from both interfaces. Binding to `10.50.220.132(255.255.252.0)` only shows packets from the expected interface. I too run Windows 7 but Python 3.6. I will check for Python 3.5

Comment: The problem exists for me also in Python 3.5. Sometimes I have to run it multiple times though before I can observe it. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This problem may be due to the packets not using the interface you are expecting. You can increase the interface metric on the interface that you *do not want* to use for routing.  This will allow the interface you *do want* to use to be preferred.

In Windows 7:

1. Goto Control Panel
2. Select Network and Sharing
3. Select Change Adapter Settings
4. Select the interface that is non-preferred for routing
5. Select Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) from the list
6. Select Advanced
7. Deselect Automatic Metric
8. Add an Interface Metric large enough to allow any other interface to be preferred.

Comment: Thanks again Stephen, you show a lot of patience! I tried that as well. First with moderate values, then with incredible high values. The wanted route had a 10 to 1000 points lower metric than any other, but still tracert shows that packets are send through both interfaces

Comment: Are these interfaces on the same subnet?  Because I use the above technique with good success.  Hmm...  Good luck.

Comment: No they have different subnets